# Customize tooltip and format the number to 2 decimal places of highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts graph to display a pie chart. I want to change the tooltip to display the actual `data` field along with the series name in place of the percentage value.

[Here is the sample at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ha3tX/)

If you check the above sample you will find 2 things

1. Tooltip is : pointFormat: '{series.name}: **{point.percentage}%**' i.e.

   Browser share: some-percentage-value

I want to show:

```
Browser share: 40 (data value instead of percentage)
```

2.  Next is the the display text for each section in the pie. One can see `n` number of decimals making the graph look very ugly.

I want to show numbers only upto 2 decimal points like `percentageDecimals: 1` used in tooltip.

I tried few things for 1st like series.data which returns an array of objects. Also series.data[0]. But no success so far

How can I do both these things?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can change it so it shows the data value instead by modifying your tooltip `pointFormat` from `pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',` to `pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}%</b>',`

You can round the numbers by using the `Highcharts.numberFormat()` function like so in your formatter:

```js
formatter: function() {
    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) +' %';
}
```

Comment: This is correct and it works but this is not the exact answer am looking for. Your answer changes the labels instead of the tooltip. Although I an solve my first doubt by using `point.y` in the tooltip to get the data. But the 2nd questions is still unanswered.

Comment: Sorry I reread the question and updated my answer, please check again

Answer (score 69):

You can use [Format Strings](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) to help you format numbers and dates.

### x Decimal Places

#### [View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/AYWsW/)

```
// point.percentage = 29.9345816
pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.0f}%' // returns: `30%` - (rounds to nearest)
pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.1f}%' // returns: `29.9%`
pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.2f}%' // returns: `29.93%`
pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.3f}%' // returns: `29.935%`
```

### Thousands separator

#### [View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/rmTWS/)

```
// point.percentage = 1029.9
{point.percentage:,.0f} // returns: `1,030`
{point.percentage:,.1f} // returns: `1,029.9`
```

---

#### Read More in the documentation:

[Documentation: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)

Comment: Does it support any other options? Where can I find a reference for this type of number formatting?

Comment: The second code block is interesting. Does that work for increasing amounts of commas, e.g.: `1,000,029.9`? Do I need to change that to `{point.percentage:,,.1.f}`?

Comment: Does it still support percentage formatting? Documentation does not have this information. Also, I tried pointFormat: '{point.percentage:.0f}%' in JSFiddler but it doesn't work.

Comment: @developer I'm not sure about newer versions of highcharts, but you should be able to use a custom formatter callback as described here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#formatter-callbacks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed description about tooltip formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

```
this.point (not shared) / this.points[i].point (shared)
```

And try `this.points[i].point` if `this.point` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach to show the actual data values is to omit the formatter function. The tooltip will default to show the actual data.